# Cannot get $_FILE["name"]["tmp_name"] when website host in centos vmware

Tags: php, linux, joomla, permissions, centos

I build an web server using centos os and i upload an joomla source code.
 Website run fine!But when i upload an file,some files i can get `$_FILE["name"]["tmp_name"]`,some files i cannot get `$_FILE["name"]["tmp_name"]`
 I don't know the reason.
 Exp:

```
$attachment = $_FILES['upload'];
echo "<pre>";
print_r($attachment);
```

Output:
On centos os:

```
    Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => myfile.zip
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => //cannot get
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => //cannot get
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
        )
}
```

on window:

```
    Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => myfile.zip
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => application/octet-stream
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpC2D7.tmp
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
        )
}
```

Thanks for watching!

Answer (score 0):

Check php.ini to be sure you have a temp path for it the file.

```
upload_tmp_dir = [something or commented out to accept a server default]
```

Comment: Yes,i did.In etc/php.ini.upload_tmp_dir= "/tmp"

Comment: Have you tried removing that and letting apache set the temp path default?

Comment: Ok,i tried to remove that and set temp default.But some files i can get $_FILES["name"]["tmp_name"] not really all.

Comment: Probably should have asked this first, but is there anything in $_FILE["error"]?